# how I could do green screen effect in ffmpeg for put a image into video with whte background using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

how I could do a green effect but instead of green color change all white color for another background

like this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgge8y9YUEs

please help me

Comment: I think it's called colorkeying. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-colorkey

Comment: yes is this but I dont know how use

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877684/chroma-key-my-command-for-filter-white-background-works-but-filter-white-and-bla