# chroma key my command for filter white background works but filter white and black?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg    -i  bakground.avi   -i overlay.avi    -filter_complex       "[1:v]chromakey=0xFFFFFF:0.02:0[keyed];       [0:v][keyed]overlay[out]"    -map "[out]"    output.avi
```

this command filter white and black

I need filter only white color

please help me

Answer (score 0):

this command works better

```
ffmpeg -y  -i background-720p.mp4 -i foreground-720p.mp4  -filter_complex '[1:v]colorkey=0xFFFFFF\:0.05\:0[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]' -map '[out]' -t 10 greenScreen.mp4
```

thanks for help

from this page

http://dragonquest64.blogspot.com/2017/04/ffmpeg-green-screen-chroma-key-for.html